Does there exist a more "quantitative" version of length for Noetherian or Artinian modules/rings?
I suppose this is a rather odd question, or at least maybe one more suited for MathOverflow, but I'll ask this here first as I'm more acquainted with MSE. In any case, this might be more "fuzzy" than my previous questions, I apologies for that.
A Noetherian ring is a ring $R$ in which the following ascending ideal chain condition holds: for all increasing sequences $I_1 \subset I_2 \subset I_3 \subset \dots \subset I_n \subset \dots$ of ideals of $R$, there exists a rank $N$ such that the chain of ideals is eventually constant equal to $I_N$.
An Artinian ring is the exact same definition except for changing "increasing" into "decreasing" instead.
I was then essentially wondering whether there would exist (hear: has someone ever studied) some type(s) of Noetherian- or Artinian-like rings in which you could have a more quantitative version of this condition, of course at the cost of providing more (topological/geometrical/algebraic/...) information about these ideals.
By quantitative, I mean for example being able to tell which $N$ is minimal, or, given two increasing/decreasing chains of ideals which would be close enough in some sense, being able to tell how close the $N$s could be, etc...
EDIT: with the vocabulary that Brian Moehring kindly introduced me to in his comment below, I think a more precise way to phrase my question, or at least to give it more focus instead of being too vague, would be:

Does there exist some concept of "Noetherian or Artinian module/ring of locally finite length" where, given some notion of "locality", for example a topological one, you could quantify what happens to the length of submodule/ideal chains which are "close enough", like for example giving an upper bound on their length?
${}$
To circumvent the issue of "degenerate" chains, once could maybe identify chains with multiple copies of the same submodule to the chain where every duplicate is dismissed, possibly by taking a quotient on the space of chains of submodules.

I wouldn't be surprised nor too bothered if it's not really something that's possible to rigorously define nor something that'd be truly useful even if put into place correctly. I just wanted to ask this out of curiosity anyway.
Feel free to edit or re-tag if/when appropriate.

If I understand your question correctly, you seem to be asking how to quantify the length of an artinian ring [as a module over itself].  Is that accurate?

@BrianMoehring Oh it seems like that's the exact notion I was thinking of, thanks for the keyword length. I suppose this is indeed what I'm asking then, yes. (Sorry for the late response.)
